# List of only installed apps in Google Play on PC

Tags: google-play-store

I'd like to see a list of installed apps on my PC by using Google Play. If I go to the link https://play.google.com/apps, it shows me installed apps, but also the apps I used in the past which now are uninstalled. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It is no longer possible

You used to be able to do this on a PC by visiting the [Playstore's your apps page](https://play.google.com/apps).  This was well explained in [Izzy's](https://android.stackexchange.com/) answer in 2014 on Web Applications' sister site [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) to the question: [View Installed Apps on particular Device on play.google.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/93078/)

Unfortunately that is no longer possible and you must do it from your Android device.

Comment: Hello @BlindSpots thank you very much for your answer.